# Check if connection to database can be established

Tags: c#

I need to write a C# program that is scheduled to run everyday and runs a series of tests to ensure everything's running good. It checks to see for net connection, server connection, database connection etc.

The part I'm confused about it checking connection to database. Should I establish a connection with the db and then disconnect? Or is there a way to just poll the database without having to pass credentials (don't actually need to log in).

Comment: You could see if something is listening at port 1433 (default for SQL server) although that's no real guarantee whatsoever that you have a (fully) functioning instance. Multiple monitoring tools do exist which can check the whole spectrum of available services / servers etc...

Comment: Which database server are you using? Looking at the answers there could be a server specific solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to connect to the database using invalid credentials and then examine the error code to see if you got an "access denied" error as opposed to "connection failed" or something else. Whether this is reliably doable depends on your database server of choice, which you failed to mention.

The easiest way would be to just use the correct credentials, though.

Comment: The reason I don't mention the database server is because we run multiple database servers of different types and my program needs to be able to handle all of them, preferably without the user needing to specify the same. I will try connecting with wrong credentials and see its a reasonable way to achieve what I intend. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MySql Offers a `Connection.Ping()` method that returns true or false even if you haven't called `Connection.Open()` before.

However, I prefer to not perform such kind of preflight checks but rather handle exceptions if something goes wrong (Even if Connection.Ping() returns true you can't be sure that the server is still available during the next command)

Comment: This might work for me. I don't have to really issue any command. Just check that the database is up or not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achive but a good test would be to execute `SELECT SYSDATE()` and compare if that DateTime value with greater than the last one queried. That does not only ensure that the server is reachable but also works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what do you exactly mean by "checking connection to the database". Problems can arise at many levels. For example in the case of SQL Server, if you read this article, there are many ways something can fail: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827422/en

The best is really to connect, do a SELECT 1 or alike, and check the return.

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert but i assume you mean MS Sql server? Database server could be more or less any thing...

If the program is running on the same server or has access to it you could check if the database service is up and running but im not 100% sure if that gives you the info you need..

Edit:

You could also try to use the "[SqlDataSourceEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.aspx)" to find the instance

Comment: We run servers of various types including Sql server, my sql and oracle. My program needs to be able to handle all of them, preferably without the user needing to worry about it.

Comment: well if you have to be 100% sure they are running correctly you will have to connect and run some thing simple..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ServiceController class in System.Service process to check that the DB service is running.

But then you could still get an instance where the service is running but the DB is not accepting connections. So, for me the only sure way would be to connect and run a simple query

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't do something like this? Obviously this isn't as specific, but you could fill in the blanks.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   try
   {
      con.Open();
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      // Cant Connect
   }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't the connection string include the credentials? I'm trying to avoid having to worry about credentials since I won't actually be issuing any commands.

Comment: True, you would need to pass credential in a non trusted connection, but if the connection is trusted then you wouldnt have to.

Comment: How does the concept of a "trusted connection" apply to, say, MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

We can either check if the connection is open or not.

```C#
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
```

Don't forget **using System.Data;**